# Logstash sql_last_value is not updating

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I wish to migrate records from one mysql table to elasticsearch by using logstash configuration. I'm checking that file logstash_jdbc_last_run_issued is not changing/updating so the sql_last_value is not changing also. When I add one record on table artifact, the index emp7 is inserting with replicating information without stopping. So it's growing and growing the index. Unless I break up the logstash process.

Logstash configuration:

```
input {
 jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "e:\Data\logstash\bin\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/kibana"
        jdbc_user => "userdb"
        jdbc_password => "passdb"
        last_run_metadata_path => "e:\Data\logstash\bin\logstash_jdbc_last_run_issued"
        tracking_column => "issuedDate"
        tracking_column_type => "numeric"
        use_column_value=>true
        statement => "SELECT serial, name, issuedDate FROM artifact where issuedDate > :sql_last_value;  "
        schedule => " * * * * * *"  
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://127.0.0.1:9200"
        index => "emp7"
        document_type => "doc"
        user => "user"
        password => "pass"
    }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

Table structure information: artifact

```
serial     varchar(40)
name       varchar(40)
issuedDate bigint(20)
```

I'm giving you logstash debug results:

```
[2019-12-30T11:38:46,004][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] (0.000000s) SELECT serial, name, issuedDate FROM artifact where issuedDate > 0;
[2019-12-30T11:38:46,004][WARN ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] tracking_column not found in dataset. {:tracking_column=>"issuedDate"}
```

file logstash_jdbc_last_run_issued content:

```
--- 0
```

I'm using logstash 6.0, elasticsearch 6.0 and kibana 6.0

My question is what is missing about logstash configuration?

Comment: I think the elasticsearch output pluggin needs a host value in an array. not sure if this fixes it but try it out. Look at this : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.8/config-examples.html

Comment: I updated to: hosts => ["http://127.0.0.1:9200"] but same result. The thing is logstash has to insert the document only once because I added one record to the mysql table but it's replicating and again the same record without stopping.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out what it's happening.
The problem was related to tracking_column not found in dataset. {:tracking_column...}.

I added lowercase_column_names => false inside jdbc section. Additionally, I added clean_run => false. Finally it starts to work. I was understaning logstash lowercases the tracking_column by default. So I disabled that.

```
input {
 jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "e:\Data\logstash\bin\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/kibana"
        jdbc_user => "userdb"
        jdbc_password => "passdb"
        last_run_metadata_path => "e:\Data\logstash\bin\logstash_jdbc_last_run_issued"
        tracking_column => "issuedDate"
        use_column_value=>true
        lowercase_column_names => false
        clean_run => false
        statement => "SELECT serial, name, issuedDate FROM artifact where issuedDate > :sql_last_value;  "
        schedule => " * * * * * *"  
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["http://127.0.0.1:9200"]
        index => "emp7"
        document_type => "doc"
        user => "user"
        password => "pass"
    }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case, I didn't need the column to be put into the elasticsearch index, so I wasn't selecting it in the statement (it was just part of the WHERE clause).  It wasn't clear to me that it needed to be in the statement, but I guess it makes sense so logstash doesn't have to grab it some other way.